# Obtaining available cores on an android device C++

Tags: android, c++, linux-kernel

I am trying to obtain a bitmap of the number of cores which are online in an android device. I am trying to create a command line tool in C++ that does some additional functionality based on how many cores are on and in particular which cores are available.

I have tried to use the following to try and get the number of cores on in C++:

```
cpus = sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN );
```

This gives me the number of cores in the system but not which cores are presently ON.

Does anyone know a potential way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting /sys/devices/system/cpu/online and /sys/devices/system/cpu/offline and the other sysfs entries for processors?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to get the core status by looking at this directory

Comment: Also note that this is not a normal directory.  It is tied into the file system, but is part of sysfs.  This particular part of sysfs is used to communicate between the kernel and user space  CPU status.

Answer (score 0):

There's no clear cut answer to this problem.

You can use [`nproc`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-get-number-of-cpus-core-command/) to see how many cores you have available, but this won't tell you *how many cores you have online*.

You can use [`top`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm) to view the utilization of each core. You can then parse the information from `top` to *infer which cores are presently on*.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the core online status using this:

```
int numCPU = 1; 
char *status = (char*)calloc(32,sizeof(char));
char *directory = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));    
sprintf(directory, "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/online", numCPU);
FILE *online = fopen(directory, "r");
if(online)
{
   size = fread(status, sizeof(char), 32, online);
}
printf("Core %d status=%d", numCPU, status);
```